# How to extract subtitle from usm file

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, extract

I would like to extract subtitle.txt from usm file, I tried use ffmpeg but it show unspuported file. Hexedit show that file has txt extension. Ffmpeg support demux cri usm file, but I cant figure out how to do it.

```
  Duration: 00:03:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12383 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 104857 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 4554752 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: none, 44100 Hz, 2 channels
  Stream #0:2: Audio: none, 44100 Hz, 2 channels
  Stream #0:3: Audio: none, 44100 Hz, 2 channels
  Stream #0:4: Audio: none, 44100 Hz, 2 channels
  Stream #0:5: Audio: none, 44100 Hz, 2 channels
  Stream #0:6: Audio: none, 44100 Hz, 2 channels
  Stream #0:7: Audio: none, 44100 Hz, 2 channels
  Stream #0:8: Audio: none, 44100 Hz, 2 channels
  Stream #0:9: Audio: none, 44100 Hz, 2 channels
  Stream #0:10: Audio: none, 44100 Hz, 2 channels
  Stream #0:11: Subtitle: none
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Try : `ffmpeg -i <input> -map 0:11 -c copy -f data subtitles.txt`

Comment: `[out#0/data @ 00000240bc408d40] video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[out#0/data @ 00000240bc408d40] Output file is empty, nothing was encoded
size=       0kB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A`

I've tried this before. Doesn't work.

Comment: I think `Stream #0:11: Subtitle: none` is empty

Comment: It's not empty. It just doesn't support this format because with audio it's show same error. I could only extract wideo. I found a program called VGMToolbox that can extract audio and video. Unfortunately, I didn't find anything that could extract subtitles.

Comment: Maybe try with `-copy_unknown` option

Comment: It's same. `[sist#0:11/none @ 000001f5f36f9cc0] Decoding requested, but no decoder found for: none`

Comment: Last attempt : `ffmpeg -f data -i <input> -map 0:11 -c copy -f data subtitles.txt`

Comment: This command also has no effect.